# Accepting u in floating point numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a set of c++ files which are autogenerated by a tool which we cant change . These file are   compiled at run time based on user inputs . These files have `double f = userInputs ; definitions.  userInputs is provide by users who might provide an input of say 25u . so autogenerated file will have double f = 25u written in them . 
Now  I wish that in userInputs  u  get replaces with *1.06-6  in the code . But this is autogenerated and not in my control .

All the autogenerated code uses a file stdAfx.h which is under my control  . Can i do #define or typedef ec in this file so that the autogenerated file with double f = userInputs  gets compiled right even if user says 25u ?

Comment: which cpp standard?

Comment: Can you add a preprocessing step to your data flow?

Comment: @m.s. unless the [c++03] or [c++11] tags are used, that's C++14.

Comment: Can you write second step generator that gets generated file and replaces u with *1.06-6  on output (using regexp for example)?

Comment: @m.s its C++11 that i am using

Comment: With "1.06-6", I assume you mean "1.06e-6"?

Answer (score -1):

You could do `#define double DoubleWrapper`. `DoubleWrapper` would have a constructor taking an `unsigned int`, storing it internally as a double multiplied by the number you want. You probably want to add a plain `double` constructor too.

You should also add a cast operator to `double`, which would return it's internally stored variable.

This way your replaced double works like a double everywhere unless:

- you provide it an unsigned int
- you used it as another type without explicitly casting it, because C++ won't chain multiple implicit casts

Depending how your project is structured, this might be acceptable, or might be too much restriction.

Also note that:

- this is nonstandard, you shouldn't redefine keywords. But every compiler allows it
- it might cause hard to understand problem if this stdAfx.h is used by other parts of your project, as it changes how double behaves with generally. Since that's probably a precompiled header used by every of your files, you shouldn't do it like this.

Comment: This is a horrible idea.

Comment: It is horrible, I was very specific about that in the last part. But if it is in a well contained part of the code (not in a pch), it might work. Aslo, the question was if it could be solved with a `#define` - and the answer to that is yes, you just shouldn't do it.